# ASP.NET WebPages Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created simple asp.net project.

Have folder Account, and many files like Register.cshtml, LogIn, etc...
And url: localhost/Account/Register

Want it to be: localhost/Register, localhost/LogIn.

Tried to map it in _AppStart.cshtml:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Account", "{Action}", "~/Account/{Action}");
```

And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to use MapRoute to MapPageRoute, because MapPageRoute is (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute.aspx)):

> Provides a way o define routes for Web Forms applications

But if you modify your code like this:

```
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

     routes.MapRoute("AccountRoute", "{Action}", new {controller = "Account"});

     routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
```

Every request without parameters will go to AccountRoute, even if it should be handled by other controler.

The only way it will be working is to create code like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

//ALL routes you need
routes.MapRoute("LoginRoute", "{Action}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" });
routes.MapRoute("RegisterRoute", "{Action}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" });            

//Default route in the end
routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Default",
                    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
 //Default 
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "", 
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );

          //url rewriting

            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(null, "Register/{ID}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Register" });
```